# Kinect API record stream

Tags: c#, .net, video, kinect, record

Im new to using the Kinect SDK and I'm looking to record a session using the kinect (all three streams seperately) and then allow it to be played back later.

I've seen this article, so what i need seems to be achievable, I just need to know how: [Recording video/Image information in C# file size is huge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804659/recording-video-image-information-in-c-sharp-file-size-is-huge/17427481#17427481)

I'm most interested in the Skeleton recording.  I know that not all frames need to be captured and replayed for the RGB but if we drop frames to reduce recording size with the skeleton output, will this not degrade the accuracy of the recording?

Thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the recording. If you want to show it as a movie, 24 or 25 fps (also, see [codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec)). But of course: less data == less accuracy.

Comment: At this point Im looking to store as just the raw data that I can (somehow) run again.  Similar to how Kinect Studio works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out the answer to my question was more involved that I had first realized.  In actual fact I am recording information from the Kinect camera.  With the aim of reloading this again at a later time.

The three streams of data it gives are:

- Color (image)
- Depth (image/data)
- Skeletal (data)

Consider the following when making an informed decision:

- Is it the data or the images you are interested in?
- If images, you could save space by compressing the images.  Can you live with
  compressed images though?  Does the memory/time needed to process
  each frames compression as they arrive more important that the
  storage space for each?
- If data, how accurate do you need the data to
  be?  Is it feasible to drop frames and then later apply some
  interpolation technique to imply the points between each captured
  frame?

Hope this helps!